# Get mailing list, an outlook user is member of. With Python Pywin32

Tags: python, outlook, pywin32

The following code extracts multiple details of an exchange user in Outlook. What I need is to extract the email groups (may be name ) the user is a member of. I can't figure out how to access this attribute.

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd 
# Outlook stuff
outApp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
outGAL = outApp.Session.GetGlobalAddressList()
entries = outGAL.AddressEntries
data_set = list()

# Iterates through your contact book and extracts/appends them to a list
for entry in entries:
    if entry.Type == "EX":
        user = entry.GetExchangeUser()
        if user is not None:
            if len(user.FirstName) > 0 or len(user.LastName) > 0:
                row = list()
                row.append(user.FirstName)
                row.append(user.LastName)
                row.append(user.PrimarySmtpAddress)
                row.append(user.Department)
                row.append(user.BusinessTelephoneNumber)
                row.append(user.MobileTelephoneNumber)
                row.append(user.CompanyName)
                row.append(user.Name)
                row.append(user.JobTitle)
                row.append(user.OfficeLocation)
                row.append(user.Alias)
                row.append(user.City)
                row.append(user.Comments)
                row.append(user.StateOrProvince)
                row.append(user.StreetAddress)
                data_set.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExchangeUser.GetMemberOfList` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.getmemberoflist

Comment: It returns a method. 
`<bound method _ExchangeUser.GetMemberOfList of <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library._ExchangeUser instance at 0x2157568189512>>`  

 How to get the actual text.

Comment: Of course - it returns `AddressEntries` object. You need to loop through the list and for each member of the list (`AddressEntry` object) read its `Name` property.